# Threads in Android (NetworkOnMainThreadException with Javamail) acting very strange

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, networking, jakarta-mail

I am a beginner in Android platform and i have encountering a serious problem. I want to fetch emails from gmail and therefore i have created a class that does that. However when i run my class in android NetworkOnMainThreadException. So i have created new Thread with a new Runnable as below :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      FetchEmails e = new FetchEmails();
    }
  }).start();
}
```

It worked fine but then i can't seem to have access to e.getMessage in order to get the actual email. Having this on mind i have implement Runnable to my FetchEMails class and done all the fetch code in run() which i have overidden. The last piece of code in run() is setting a variable to 'true'. Then in my Activity class i have instantiate the class and i have done this : `new Thread(e).start();`. Below i have a while  loop to check wether the class has finished to the end of run() method (by checking if the variable is true). So now i have created my new theard which does not intefere with the UI and when the code is finished i want to get the message. But it seems that i still get the NetworkOnMainThreadException error. Any help with that is apprecieted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

Comment: I have seen AsyncTask before, so basicaly i will need to extend my Class from AsyncTask and execute all the commands in doBackground. But then when i finish fetching the emails and i store them in a say ArrayList how do i know in my Activity class that it has finished fetching and now i can access the ArrayList?

Comment: You can update your "UI" thread in `onPostExecute()`. So you can either pass a callback to the AsyncTask class or declare it as an internal class of your activity. Then you can update the adapter or target arraylist in there.